# C# Entity Framework MVC Web API

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have searched and searched and cannot find any answers. Hopefully you all can be of assistance.

I am building an MVC WebAPI app in C#.

I have added a DB connection using Entity Framework and am able to call it and load a variable with the data.

My issue is that I am trying to return the data in JSON format (I already added the line of code to my WebApiConfig.cs file to default to text/html).

Here is my code:

```
public string Get(string id)
    {
        string userName = id.ToString();

        using (var db = new SDCLogins())
        {
            var query = from logins in db.logins
                        join loginTypes in db.loginTypes on new { loginType = logins.loginType } equals new { loginType = loginTypes.loginTypeID }
                        where
                          logins.uname == userName
                        select new
                        {
                            logins.login1,
                            startDate = SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", logins.startDate) + "/" +
                            SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", logins.startDate) + "/" +
                            SqlFunctions.DateName("yyyy", logins.startDate),
                            stopDate = SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", logins.stopDate) + "/" +
                            SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", logins.stopDate) + "/" +
                            SqlFunctions.DateName("yyyy", logins.stopDate),
                            createdDate = SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", logins.createdDate) + "/" +
                            SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", logins.createdDate) + "/" +
                            SqlFunctions.DateName("yyyy", logins.createdDate),
                            logins.createdBy,
                            loginTypes.loginDescription
                        };


            return Json.Encode(query);
        }

    }
```

When I execute the response I get is different than any JSON I've seen before:

```
"[{\"login1\":\"akamau001\",\"startDate\":\"1/24/2014\",\"stopDate\":\"//\",\"createdDate\":\"10/3/2014\",\"createdBy\":\"ozzie\",\"loginDescription\":\"Login Type 1\"},{\"login1\":\"123D56\",\"startDate\":\"1/1/1900\",\"stopDate\":\"//\",\"createdDate\":\"10/3/2014\",\"createdBy\":\"ozzie\",\"loginDescription\":\"Login Type 2\"}]"
```

Firstly the // is the way I am handling the dates, any insite as to how to make those return null would be appreciated. Secondly why is everything escaped with a "\"? Is there any way to turn that off?

Comment: You are overthinking this.  WebApi does not require you to return raw JSON, you should return the literal types and those will get serialized into JSON.

Comment: For the dates, I would create a viewmodel class with `DateTime?` properties. When you map from the db model to viewmodel, assign null or use [`DateTime.ToString(string format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of that string concatenation.

Comment: You're looking at the string in the debugger where the quotes are escaped because it's a .NET string value. If you use something like Postman in Chrome you won't see the backslashes.

Comment: @Craig W.: Using Postman I still get the backslashes...I also was testing using WGET on another box and get them there too.

Comment: @JasonP can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I figured out the backslash issue. I am still stuck on the date problem though...if anyone could help with that I would be much appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the date issue by:

```
startDate = logins.startDate.HasValue ? (object) logins.startDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : DBNull.Value,
stopDate = logins.stopDate.HasValue ? (object) logins.stopDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : DBNull.Value,
createdDate = logins.createdDate.HasValue ? (object) logins.createdDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : DBNull.Value
```

Now it doesn't flip out if there is a value or if there isn't.

Also for the JSON issue:

```
public Array Get(string id)
        {
            //return "value";
            string userName = id.ToString();

            using (var db = new SDCLogins())
            {
                var query = from logins in db.logins.AsEnumerable()
                            join loginTypes in db.loginTypes on new { loginType = logins.loginType } equals new { loginType = loginTypes.loginTypeID }
                            where
                              logins.uname == userName
                            select new
                            {
                                logins.login1,
                                startDate = logins.startDate.HasValue ? (object) logins.startDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : DBNull.Value,
                                stopDate = logins.stopDate.HasValue ? (object) logins.stopDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : DBNull.Value,
                                createdDate = logins.createdDate.HasValue ? (object) logins.createdDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : DBNull.Value,
                                logins.createdBy,
                                loginTypes.loginDescription
                            };

                return query.ToArray();
            }

        }
```

Once I set the type as an array and then converted query to an array and returned that it works very much like I expected it to!

Although I didn't get a solid answer you all helped me find my way! Thanks a ton!!